# So what the heck is a "florp"?

Tags: discussion, podcast

I saw a link to the current SE podcast on the sidebar on SO and thought I'd check it out because I didn't know what a "florp" is:

[image: community-bulletin]

The bulletin didn't describe / define the word.

I Googled it and the top result is NSFW, so I won't include it here. Somehow I don't think that "florp" in the SE context is the same as the Google result.

So what the heck is a "florp"?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The titles of Stack Exchange podcasts usually come from little jokes in the recording. They don't always make it into the show notes, usually because they are just throwaway lines or passing comments from Joel. They're almost always off topic.

In this case, "florp" was a nonsense word Joel made up. You'll hear it if you listen closely to the podcast. The word's relationship to the Urban Dictionary definition (which I won't link to) and to the [Futurama character](http://futurama.wikia.com/wiki/Florp) is purely coincidental.

Comment: Wow, that's a bad word even in Urban Dictionary standards! Guess Joel wouldn't have used that word if he knew.

Comment: @ShadowWizard Yup. Yeesh.

Comment: No point renaming the podcast now, I guess? :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Maybe if we leave it, our blog post will start to outrank Urban Dictionary in search results!

Comment: Excellent point, UD got no chance against SE!

Comment: I thought maybe it was a podcasting startup company or something similar. I was way off. Thanks for the insight!